# Is there any wrong with the sentence,'The visit was treated with respect and given ten dollars'

Tags: past-participles

Whether the subject must be changed to 'the visitor'

Comment: The noun "visit" is abstract and could not be "given" anything. Whilst "visitor" is usually *homo sapiens* and could indeed be given ten dollars.

Comment: What meaning do you want to give. The word "visit" and "visitor" have clearly different meanings.  Which meaning do you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as it's written, the sentence is ungrammatical because while you can respect an event, you can't give money to it in a direct sense. (It may be syntactically okay, but not semantically.)

But based on the intention behind the sentence, there are several ways it could be meant—and then need to be rewritten.

> 1. The visitor was treated with respect and given ten dollars.

Here, it's taken as a typo and it's actually a person who was respected and given money rather than an event.

> 2. The visit was treated with respect, and its fund was given ten dollars.

Here, it's not the visit that is directly given money, but a fund that has been set up for it—something that *can* "receive" money.

> 3. The Visit was treated with respect and given ten dollars.

This is a play on words, but still a possibility. In this interpretation, there is a person who goes by the name **The Visit**. So, the only problem with the original sentence was one of punctuation. Putting it in uppercase, it's now this specific person who is both respected and given money.

> 4. The visit was treated with respect, and each visitor was given ten dollars.

In this case, it's possible to interpret the sentence in such a way that both the event and people attending it are referenced at the same time.

Comment: What about giving "the visit" ten dollars? It's grammatical but it's also nonsensical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I suppose you could "give ten dollars toward a visit fund," but that assumes something different. Or, perhaps there is somebody who goes by the name **The Visit**, in which case everything is correct—aside from the punctuation . . .

Comment: Are you saying there is nothing wrong with the actual sentence written by the OP? The proofreading question  asks: `Is there any wrong with the sentence?`

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have expanded my answer to be more comprehensive.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you. It was just a typo. (I imagine it could also be forty quarters.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reasons a lot of the time but from what I've picked up and what my teachers have taught me, I know it should be "the visitor".